# sort tuple with multiple condition

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to sort a list of tuple with 3 elements in decreasing order based on the third elements.

Input:

```
 [('a', 1, 50),('b', 2, 50),('c', 3, 25),('d',4,20),('e',5,14)]
```

My output:

```
[('b', 2, 50),('a', 1, 50),('c', 3, 25), ('d',4,20),('e',5,14)]
```

Expected output:

```
[('a', 1, 50),('b', 2, 50),('c', 3, 25), ('d', 4, 20),('e', 5, 14)]
```

I want to place additional condition when the 3rd element in the tuple are even, the tuple with smaller 2nd element will be place in front.

Thanks !

Comment: With your example input, just sorting on 3rd element will produce your expected output: `sorted(start, key = lambda x: x[2], reverse = True)`.  Consider providing example input which strictly requires the second sorting `key` argument (per @Chris's good answer).

Answer (score 4):

Use `sorted` with two `key`s and `reverse`:

```
sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: (x[2], -x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1, 50), ('b', 2, 50), ('c', 3, 25), ('d', 4, 20), ('e', 5, 14)]
```